# How to create Database sql views in symfony

Tags: sql, database, symfony

I am not getting idea how to create sql views in symfony. Please can anyone help me how to create sql views in symfony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first create the test data :

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO T
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'john'),
    (2, 'henry')
;
```

---

creat view in Symfony :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(); 
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$statement = $connection->prepare("create view View_T as select * from T where id = 1;");
$statement->execute();
```

then you can use the `View_T` by Query:

```
select * from View_T
```

get the result

```
| id | name |
|----|------|
|  1 | john |
```

---

Details about view you can learn from [SQL CREATE VIEW, REPLACE VIEW, DROP VIEW Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp)

Comment: Thank you @IT weiHan, I have understood. But I am unclear in one things.Do I need to run creating view statement every time?

Comment: no, view just need create one time and use any time. when you create exist view it'll throw exception.

Comment: okay. Thank you I have understood now.Moreover, please could you tell me,How I can change collation of table in symfony. I have this query "
ALTER TABLE table_data CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;" .I think I have to run it through doctrine. I am not getting how to do

Comment: please ask another question. it'll get more detail.